# DreamSpark Windows 8.1 - Which one should I download?

Tags: windows-8, dreamspark

I have the following options to pick from, which one?

- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional 32/64-bit (English) - DreamSpark
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional 32/64-bit (English-United Kingdom) - DreamSpark
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional N with Update 32/64-bit (English) - DreamSpark
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional N with Update 32/64-bit (English-United Kingdom) - DreamSpark
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional with Update 32/64-bit (English) - DreamSpark
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional with Update 32/64-bit (English-United Kingdom) - DreamSpark

Also, do I need any of the following? I like to type in Chinese and wouldn't mind making my entire UI Chinese either. But I'd like English and Chinese too.

- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Language Pack (Multilanguage) - DreamSpark
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Symbols 32/64-bit (English) - DreamSpark

Answer (score 5):

[About the "N" versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/n-editions): "This version of Windows 8.1 Pro N includes the same functionality as Windows 8.1 Pro, except that it doesn't include certain media-related technologies (Windows Media Player, Music, Video, Skype)"

"With Update", as I understand it, just means that the latest Service Pack / Updates are also included.